# How refresh items on a content page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I read a lot of topics about usage of ObservableCollection, but I don't understand what should I do in my case. I have the following `PageContent` structure:

[image]

I use IList collection to store my `Xamarin.Form.Image`. I take it from the database. The number of the grid layout rows and columns definitely depend on the number of images in a database. User can load new images to a database. It ads to a database by using `ImageRepository` and it ads to the `IList<T>` collection, but I don't know how to dynamically redraw my grid layout. I tried to do this as follows:

```
//this.images 
//is a IList<Images> which stores as property of the class.

        private void OnClickSearchImagesButton(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            IFiler filer = DependencyService.Get<IFiler>();
            // Get all paths of the images
            IEnumerable<string> filesPath = filer.GetFilesPaths(FileExtension.JPG);
            IEnumerable<Image> images = filesPath.Select(f => new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromFile(f) });

            foreach (Image img in images)
            {
                // If found image does not exist
                // Add it to a database
                // --------------------

                // Redraw grid layout
                this.gridLayout = new Grid();

                const int numberOfImagesPerRow = 3;
                int numberOfImages = this.images.Count;
                int numberOfRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)numberOfImages / numberOfImagesPerRow);

                // configure grid layout
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
                {
                    this.gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(200) });
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImagesPerRow; i++)
                {
                    this.gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                }

                for (int i = 0, imageNumber = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfImagesPerRow && imageNumber < numberOfImages; j++, imageNumber++)
                    {
                        this.gridLayout.Children.Add(images[imageNumber], j, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it didn't help me. I saw some topics when people use `ObservableCollection` for items instead of `List`. I'm a little bit confused with it, because I think that I need to store all my items in ObservableCollection. Please, could you explain me what is the best way to hold actual information on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObservableCollection is very useful when you use controls like ListView. If you add a record or remove a record from the ObservableCollection, ListView updates automatically.

If you create a Grid and add Images to it, you should add or remove items "by code". ObservableCollection can't help you.

If you need a ListView that display images (so you can use ObservableCollection) you can take a look to

[FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)

it's a powerful plugin that can visualize Images in a List

DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector support

Fixed or automatic column count

Grouping support

Columns can expand to empty space (configurable)

ANY View can be used as a cell

All Xamarin.Forms platforms supported

Simple sample

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

If you need a demo

[DEMO](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/Samples/DLToolkitControlsSamples/SamplesFlowListView)

Comment: FlowListView is a good suggestion, but it's not accurate to say observableCollection isn't helpful without a pre-baked control to consume it. The advantage of ObservableCollection is the events it fires when the collection is modified. Controls like ListView take advantage of this by subscribing and updating appropriately when they fire. You can also do this with your own control.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection is helpful because it fires events when the collection changes, but you need to either use a control that consumes those events, or create one yourself. In your case, I would suggest looking at some third party controls that layout images as you want (another answer mentioned FlowListView), or look at [creating a custom layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom/) in Xamarin Forms.